# Staging test: Listener not resolving - TimeOut Error ( ChainLink Solidity Course)

Tags: testing, ethers.js, hardhat, chainlink, chainlink-keepers

```
  Raffle Staging Tests
    fulfillRandomWords
Setting up test...
Setting up Listener...
Entering Raffle...
Ok, time to wait...
All Good here!!!
      1) works with live Chainlink Keepers and Chainlink VRF, we get a random winner


  0 passing (8m)
  1 failing
```

**Problem:**

Code runs properly until listener tries to listen to `raffle.once("WinnerPicked", async () => { }`

- It fails to resolve the try/catch block
- It fails to call upkeep but calls vrf succesfully (transactions for 0.1 ETH registered)

**Error:**

```
Error: Timeout of 500000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
```

================================================================

**Code Block:**

```
          describe("fulfillRandomWords", function () {
              it("works with live Chainlink Keepers and Chainlink VRF, we get a random winner", async function () {
                  // enter the raffle
                  console.log("Setting up test...")
                  const startingTimeStamp = await raffle.getLatestTimeStamp()
                  const accounts = await ethers.getSigners()

                  console.log("Setting up Listener...")
                  await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
                      // setup listener before we enter the raffle
                      // Just in case the blockchain moves REALLY fast
                      raffle.once("WinnerPicked", async () => {
                          console.log("WinnerPicked event fired!")
                          try {
                              // add our asserts here
                              const recentWinner = await raffle.getRecentWinner()
                              const raffleState = await raffle.getRaffleState()
                              const winnerEndingBalance = await accounts[0].getBalance()
                              const endingTimeStamp = await raffle.getLatestTimeStamp()


                              await expect(raffle.getPlayer(0)).to.be.reverted
                              assert.equal(recentWinner.toString(), accounts[0].address)
                              assert.equal(raffleState, 0)
                              assert.equal(
                                  winnerEndingBalance.toString(),
                                  winnerStartingBalance.add(raffleEntranceFee).toString()
                              )
                              assert(endingTimeStamp > startingTimeStamp)
                              resolve()
                          } catch (error) {
                              console.log(error)
                              reject(e)
                          }
                      })

                      // Then entering the raffle
                      console.log("Entering Raffle...")
                      const tx = await raffle.enterRaffle({ value: raffleEntranceFee })
                      await tx.wait(1)
                      console.log("Ok, time to wait...")
                      const winnerStartingBalance = await accounts[0].getBalance()
                      console.log("All Good here!!!")
                      // and this code WONT complete until our listener has finished listening!
                  })
              })
          })
      })
```

================================================================

**Solutions Attempted:**

- GitHub conversation: https://github.com/smartcontractkit/full-blockchain-solidity-course-js/discussions/729

| When removed alters the code and functionality & does not fix the problem in my case

```
(bool upkeepNeeded, ) = checkUpkeep("");
      if (!upkeepNeeded) {
          revert Raffle__UpkeepNotNeeded(
              address(this).balance,
              s_players.length,
              uint256(s_raffleState)
          );
      }
```

- GitHub conversation: https://github.com/smartcontractkit/full-blockchain-solidity-course-js/discussions/967
- Google search + Forums

| 5 days spent researching a solution but still no success...

================================================================

**Steps to reproduce:**

- GitHub Repo:  https://github.com/DorianDaSilva/RaffleStagingDebug

================================================================

**Repo:**

Chainlink Solidity Course: https://github.com/PatrickAlphaC/hardhat-smartcontract-lottery-fcc

- ../test/staging/Raffle.staging.test.js

================================================================

I would appreciate if someone could help me figure out how to fix the problem block or code so it runs as originally intended.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, It looks like there was a suggestion on the GitHub discussion. Have you tried that? Also, I think it would be best to keep the conversation in one place, and GH might be best for it. I'll look for a response to the suggestion over there.

Comment: Hi Richard, thank you for the input. I did try the suggestion but it doesn't work in my case besides from altering the functionality of the code. I usually keep it on GH but since this has been an ongoing issue for the past 5 days I decided to expand the scope of the conversation hoping to pin point a solution.